# How to get average app review from iTunes/App store API?

Tags: ios, json, app-store

I'm trying to get the average star review rating (as it would be displayed on the app store) for an app. Does anyone know if this is possible? I have managed to get a list of most recent reviews, and all reviews, which does show the stars the user has given it. However, I'd like the average number of stars a user gives, as it would be shown on the app store? I have tried this query:

`http://itunes.apple.com/lookup?id=my_id_here`

This gives very similar details such as price, current version etc, but does not display ratings. Does anyone know the correct query? I looked a the documentation but struggled to see an option.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 1):

This endpoint returns "averageUserRating" which sounds like what you're looking for.